# g77 : ld: warnings on version-min, and on object file

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, gfortran, g77

I need help compiling old legacy fortran with g77 :

**(1)** The system on OS X 10.12.6, XCode 9.2, and g77 -v returns "Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8.8.1/3.4.0/specs Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.0/configure --enable-languages=f77 Thread model: posix gcc version 3.4.0)"

**(2)** When compiling with a number of legacy flags :
"g77 -ffixed-line-length-132 -fbounds-check -fvxt -ftypeless-boz -finit-local-zero -fno-automatic *.f -o a.out"
I get these linker warnings :

- "ld: warning: **-macosx_version_min not specified**, assuming 10.6"
- "ld: warning: object file (/var/folders/6t/mmq9jmq88xjfvk0059b07_yh0000gn/T//ccBEadOC.o) was **built for newer OSX** version (10.12) than being linked (10.6)"

I think the solution is to set macosx_version_min to 10.12.6 but do not know how to do this.

All help gratefully received : the problem arose when I did a macports update which broke things which were working fine under 10.12.6 yesterday, albeit with the warning "ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.6".
The same code still compiles and runs just fine on a UNIX server with g77-v reporting "gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-19.el6)"

I'm hoping there's an answer starting "here's how to specify macox_version_min"

Thank you all !

Comment: Why are you using g77 3.4.0, which has not been supported by GCC for over 17 years?  Have you tried gfortran?  It is suppose to be backwards compatible with g77, but has the advantage that gfortran is under active development.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reponse. I tried gfortran, there are too many deprecated/deleted features.

I could edit the routine, all 33,000 lines of them, of course.

Yet finding a compiler which works seems preferable :) It was working yesterday. I have a bootable backup done just before, in order to be able to roll back. I'm considering it.

And note : it's a legacy program: active development is not an issue.

Comment: You likely need the `-std=legacy` option.  This will permit a boat load of questionable extensions.  Is the code available someplace?

Comment: It used to be, but the Spanish webite went down.
In the meantime, I rowed back and am now on my good old system before yesterday' macports update. Beware the macport!

I'd be glad to make the source code available, there's a distribution / installation package of sorts. Though it' a big mess : a program built up by academics over many years, like the leaves of autumn (mostly me).

Comment: p.s. adding -std=legacy to gfortran raises errors, as opposed to just warnings without, but so many warnings it stops.
That is : gfortran -std=legacy -ffixed-line-length-132 -fbounds-check -finit-local-zero -fno-automatic solj.f jq.f jrad.f nag-for-sol.f eff.f mirror.f eldata.f  mqwpars.f tunnel.f -o a.out
New errors such as"Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute"
And : "FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!"

Comment: I would need to see the code.  That "... function result on the lhs ..." error seems to be rather odd for `-std=legacy` to trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236223/discussion-between-jpgconnolly-and-steve).